# Flow interaction As3 -> PHP -> Mysql-> C++

Tags: php, c++, mysql, actionscript-3

I have a webpage that serves as GUI to PHP-MySQL, but i want to make signal processing of the data stored in the database, i appreciate if anyone could tell me whats a good solution to communicate to my C++ programs, i was thinking about making the PHP code write "jobs" in a file, and run the C++ that read that, and execute the processing, or maybe get an Agent Based approach and keep monitoring some folders for activity and process the data via direct files. Examples already tested, or performance advice is welcome.

Let me rephrase the problem, i don't want people vomiting random answers of how to do this, i also would like to know why you pick that answer.

Comment: Check out something like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)

Comment: Can you elaborate why Gearman could be a good option? I see that's a way to solve the problem, but i would like to know why its better than the approach that i already commented.

Comment: Using Gearman will basically give you a common communication medium between your PHP and C++ workers. It basically implements the mechanism you're trying to re-invent.

Comment: Thank you for your inner thougt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice, but i found that it's easier and faster, using MySQL Connector to read a table with "Jobs" and when a job is submitted by AS->PHP->MySQL, C++ reacts, read the data directly from the database, and execute the function needed, another table is used to get parameters from the job to execute. Just FYI, the jobs have a node field, that allows me to use 4 computers to make the execution of the data processing.